# I installed heartbeat in my drupal site and my administrative tools stopped working until i deleted it and then refreshed the site. What can i do?

Tags: heartbeat

I installed heartbeat in my drupal site and my administrative tools stopped working until i deleted it and then refreshed the site. What can i do? I had to install heartbeat to continue with my project. Please i need your help.

Comment: what are you defining as administrative tools? the menu, /admin pages? Admin Tools module?

Comment: I mean, the admin tools Mr.Geoff, any help pls?